# Segmentation fault in assembly code

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault

I am studying the book Hacking by Jon Erickson. The following code is from his book:

```
BITS 32
jmp short two     ; Jump down to the bottom for the call trick.
one:
pop ebx           ; Ebx has the addr of the string.
xor eax, eax      ; Put 0 into eax.
mov [ebx+7], al   ; Null terminate the /bin/sh string.
mov [ebx+8], ebx  ; Put addr from ebx where the AAAA is.
mov [ebx+12], eax ; Put 32-bit null terminator where the BBBB is.
lea ecx, [ebx+8]  ; Load the address of [ebx+8] into ecx for argv ptr.
lea edx, [ebx+12] ; Edx = ebx + 12, which is the envp ptr.
mov al, 11        ; Syscall #11
int 0x80          ; Do it.
two:
call one          ; Use a call to get string address.
db '/bin/shXAAAABBBB'     ; The XAAAABBBB bytes aren't needed.
```

It spawns a shell. I tried to run using:

```
nasm -f elf shellcode.asm
ld -o shellcode shellcode.o
./shellcode
```

However, I got the following error:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Previous examples from this book worked, so I do not know what is the problem. I am not an expert in assembly, it could happen that the problem is very simple.

Answer (score 0):

Typically (on modern Linux) an executable file's `.text` section is "read only", so it should cause a page fault exception (attempting to write to a "read only" page); and this is often called a "segmentation fault" on *nix systems for historical reasons.

I would also assume that this code is meant to be on the stack (e.g. where the attacker injects it as a string into a process by abusing a buffer overflow bug); which explains why it tries so hard to avoid zero bytes (as you can't have zero bytes inside a zero terminated string). In that case (on modern Linux) the stack should be "no execute" and it should cause a page fault exception (attempting to execute data in a "no execute" page).

Mostly; you're learning about security holes that were well known and fixed about 10 years before the book was published.